# Avoid asking password if `su -m user command` is used under `user`?

Tags: users, non-root-user, su, pam

If I run the script containing `su -m user service userservice start` under root user, I do not need to enter the password. But when I run it under `user` user, it asks passwords all the time. That really bugs me. Is it supposed to ask passwords for security reasons? Is there any way I could avoid asking password if `su -m user command` is run under `user`?

**Edit1:** The reason I need to avoid password entering on `su` for current user is `/etc/init.d/scripts` which have `su -m user` statement for many services I have installed. And it is seems stupid to enter password every time if I'm restarting service which is supposed to run under current user. Actually, I need to enter password twice while I'm restarting some service. I might agree that it is a feature of *some* init.d scripts and all I need to do is tweak the source a little bit, but I thought that it might be fixed somehow on the `su` level in order to avoid changing init.d scripts source code.

Comment: I suggest your script discover whether it's already running as user and only perform su if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, security is the reason and no, `su` has no way of circumventing that. But there is `sudo`, which can be used for what you want and it has a configuration file where you can disable the need to enter a password.

It also allows for complex configurations so that you can disable the need for a password for a very specific command only, to not fully void security.

`su` mostly uses pam for authentication and you could modify your `/etc/pam.d/su` and add a line

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if user = <put username here> quiet
```

With that line added you shouldn't have to enter a password, when running `su` as the specified user.

Comment: Actually its not `su` doing this. It's pam (well, assuming the system uses PAM). And you can probably change the pam config to avoid it.

Comment: Exactly, so `su` has no way of circumventing that. `sudo` is built for exactly what the OP want's to do, so he should rather use that then starting to fiddle with su's pam config.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that you want to do a `su` to yourself is really weird. It makes me worry that you've misunderstood something fundamental, as I'm having a hard time coming up with a reason why you'd ever need to do this.

Second, `su`'s password prompting is actually controlled by PAM (as is most password prompting) if your system uses PAM. Certainly, all major Linux distros do. For example, here is the top of `/etc/pam.d/su` from my Debian machine:

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `su' service
#

# This allows root to su without passwords (normal operation)
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

That first uncommented line is why root is not asked for a password. If you commented it out, root would be prompted for a password (and you'd probably break a lot of scripts!).

I don't know of a default pam module intended to compare the current and destination user, but you could use pam_exec.so to do it. Something like this (which, I confess, I'm unsure of the security implications of):

```
auth       sufficient pam_exec.so seteuid quiet /usr/local/sbin/pam-same-user
```

where `/usr/local/sbin/pam-same-user` is a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "$PAM_USER" = "$PAM_RUSER" ]
```

Once again, I'd like to stress I'm unsure of the security implications of this.

Comment: the reason I need to avoid password entering on `su` for current user is /etc/init.d/scripts which have `su -m user` statement for many services I have installed. and it is seems stupid to enter password every time if I'm restarting service under current user. actually, I need to enter password twice while I'm restarting some service. I might agree that it is a feature of *some* init.d scripts, but I thought that it might be fixed somehow on the `su` level in order to avoid changing source code of init.d scripts.

Comment: @altern I'd suggest just using sudo for that. Grant whichever user access to run `service *whatever* restart` (etc.) as root, without a password prompt. Then just use `sudo service *whatever* restart`.